# Picture description in zim wiki 0.64

Tags: formatting, pictures, zim

I use zim for more than a year, but probably in very simple way. Is it possible to add description to a picture which I attached? Is there any command, or maybe a template?
I can simply write above or bellow the picture, which does not look very nice.

Comment: You're talking about linking a description to an image as well as positioning it next to the image (making the image and description a unit)?

Comment: Probably, I am used from latex for some picture description, and in zim I do not know the syntax or even if it is possible. For example like here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions